# Finding position of a matrix

Tags: delphi

following code to show on which rectangle from a Picture Matrix 64x64 Pixels the mouse is located

how could this code be simplified ?
is a solution with arrays possible ?

X,Y ( mouse )

// Code gets rectangle at X,Y position from an Image 2048x2048 pixels each rectangle 64x64 pixels

I : Tpoint

case X of

```
0 .. 63:
  I.X := 0;
64 .. 127:
  I.X := 1;
128 .. 191:
  I.X := 2;
192 .. 255:
  I.X := 3;
256 .. 319:
  I.X := 4;
320 .. 383:
  I.X := 5;
384 .. 447:
  I.X := 6;
448 .. 511:
  I.X := 7;
512 .. 575:
  I.X := 8;
576 .. 639:
  I.X := 9;
640 .. 703:
  I.X := 10;
704 .. 767:
  I.X := 11;
768 .. 831:
  I.X := 12;
832 .. 895:
  I.X := 13;
896 .. 959:
  I.X := 14;
960 .. 1023:
  I.X := 15;
1024 .. 1087:
  I.X := 16;
1088 .. 1151:
  I.X := 17;
1152 .. 1215:
  I.X := 18;
1216 .. 1279:
  I.X := 19;
1280 .. 1343:
  I.X := 20;
1344 .. 1407:
  I.X := 21;
1408 .. 1471:
  I.X := 22;
1472 .. 1535:
  I.X := 23;
1536 .. 1599:
  I.X := 24;
1600 .. 1663:
  I.X := 25;
1664 .. 1727:
  I.X := 26;
1728 .. 1791:
  I.X := 27;
1792 .. 1855:
  I.X := 28;
1856 .. 1919:
  I.X := 29;
1920 .. 1983:
  I.X := 30;
1984 .. 2048:
  I.X := 31;
```

end;

case Y of

```
0 .. 63:
  I.Y := 0;
64 .. 127:
  I.Y := 1;
128 .. 191:
  I.Y := 2;
192 .. 255:
  I.Y := 3;
256 .. 319:
  I.Y := 4;
320 .. 383:
  I.Y := 5;
384 .. 447:
  I.Y := 6;
448 .. 511:
  I.Y := 7;
512 .. 575:
  I.Y := 8;
576 .. 639:
  I.Y := 9;
640 .. 703:
  I.Y := 10;
704 .. 767:
  I.Y := 11;
768 .. 831:
  I.Y := 12;
832 .. 895:
  I.Y := 13;
896 .. 959:
  I.Y := 14;
960 .. 1023:
  I.Y := 15;
1024 .. 1087:
  I.Y := 16;
1088 .. 1151:
  I.Y := 17;
1152 .. 1215:
  I.Y := 18;
1216 .. 1279:
  I.Y := 19;
1280 .. 1343:
  I.Y := 20;
1344 .. 1407:
  I.Y := 21;
1408 .. 1471:
  I.Y := 22;
1472 .. 1535:
  I.Y := 23;
1536 .. 1599:
  I.Y := 24;
1600 .. 1663:
  I.Y := 25;
1664 .. 1727:
  I.Y := 26;
1728 .. 1791:
  I.Y := 27;
1792 .. 1855:
  I.Y := 28;
1856 .. 1919:
  I.Y := 29;
1920 .. 1983:
  I.Y := 30;
1984 .. 2048:
  I.Y := 31;
```

end;
// end code

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about my bad formatted post , my first post on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer division (I hope `.. 2048` is mistake)

```
I.X := X div 64;
I.Y := Y div 64;
```

Comment: this is an Genial answer this is the simplest code i could not think of , thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Alfred. I see that you already got an answer to your question and a good one. Please read [this page about what to do when somebody answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). By clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer, you indicate that you consider that answer to be the best for you. And for a brief intro on this site, please also take the [tour].